Перевести json массив в массив C#
У меня есть сервер на Flask, через него я получаю данные из БД. Как мне перевести их в массив на C#



Если это ваш JSON, то он изначально ужасный, отвратительный, ибо это просто каша из типов, без какой либо структуры. Яб посоветовал вам его структурировать правильно. Вот что такое 1? Наверно ID, так почему не сделать свойство Id тогда? А Массажи - это что? Наверно "Название", верно? Ну вот уже у вас JSON с двумя свойствами..., где понятно что и за что отвечает. Ну а так, если хотите этот JSON всеж прочитать, то у вас класс, внутри которого свойство Services с типом "массив массивов object типа" (пример List<List<object>>).

"Наверно "Название", верно?" - нет, название - это например "Война и Мир" - тоже название; суть тут в том, что если вы ищите обобщающую абстракцию на это всё - так и найдите её, а она даже написана - это services, т.е. это услуги и есть; конкретного json-a в данном случае я не касаюсь

@InterceptorTSK Если вы обращаетесь к кому либо, то указывайте его ник. Предположу, что комментарий выше адресован мне. Чтож, отвечаю - Услуга (объект) из чего состоит? Из ее названия, мб описания, цены, наверно "типа", и так далее. То есть class Service { int Id, string Name, string Description, double Price, ServiceType Type } (псевдокод), если делать как говорите вы, то это будет ужасно выглядеть, ибо класс описывающий объект будет зваться "Service" и свойство с ее "именем" будет "Service", в итоге будет service.Service. Так что да, это "название" (Title/Name).

@EvgeniyZ тут нет никаких объектов, тут абстракции, абстракции абстрагируются к родительской "обобщающей" абстракции, и это не ооп [впрочем ооп слегка похоже, но суть принципиально иная]

@InterceptorTSK Ошибаетесь, объекты тут еще как есть, по крайней мере должны быть. JSON это сериализация объектов, где [ ] - массив, { } - класс, а "...": ... - свойство. То, что человек создал "кривой" JSON и хочет из него получить конфетку - это не отменяет того факта, что в JSON должна быть четкая структура объектов, а в C# должна быть аналогичная структура классов, описывающие эти объекты. В текущем виде, JSON из вопроса, это как я и сказал выше List<List<object>>, набор белеберды, с которой трудно будет каким либо образом работать в будущем.

@EvgeniyZ в любых абстрактных данных - должны быть абстрактные данные, и json никаких объектов никогда не определяет и не должен, json описывает глобальные абстракции, и иногда частично реализацию оного, и естественно json может быть всегда дополнен, но опять же есть неизменяемая часть, а есть изменяемая часть, так вот id: 3, service: "Маски" - это и есть неизменяемая часть сервиса, а всякие text/title/name - это изменяемая часть этого сервиса; неизменяемую часть обычно выделяют как либо и никогда не трогают - это часть исключительно для внутреннего пользования

@InterceptorTSK Как скажете, как скажете. Жду вашего ответа тогда, раз у вас иная точка зрения...

Код надо вставлять текстом.

Для начала создайте объект, в который будет десериализоваться ваш Json. Ваш Json выглядит крайне неправильным, вам нужно поправить Select чтобы выглядел json как то так:
    {
  "services": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Массаж"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Маски"
    }
  ]
}

После вам необходимо создать классы в проекте C#. Это можно сделать либо руками описать, либо скопировать ваш Json Правки -> специальная вставка JSON
    public class Root
{
    public List<Service> services { get; set; }
}

public class Service
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
}

После чего можете уже преобразовать свой json в класс
var services = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString)


массив сервисов - это и есть набор сервисов, но не тайтлов/имён и так далее; т.е. в массиве services - должны быть наборы из [пример]: id: 3, service: "Маски", а уже у конкретного сервиса может быть тайтл, саб-сервис и так далее

несколько раз прочитал ваш комментарий и ничего не понял

@InterceptorTSK подход, при котором List<List> вместо List это очень плохой подход, никто так не делает. Вам нужно учиться работать с объектами

нигде не написано мною про List<List>, и даже про List нигде не написано

Newtonsoft.Json устарел, используйте сериализатор System.Text.Json
